# Why do we use put id as a param in put method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to Increase a value in database,

```
const handleStockUpdate = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const newQuantity = event.target.restock.value;
        const quantity = {quantity: newQuantity};
        setNewCount({...book, quantity: book.quantity + parseInt(newQuantity)});
        if(newQuantity < 0){
            toast("Please enter a vlaid number")
        }
        else{
            axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/stock/${`idHeare`}`, {quantity})
            
        }
            
    }
```

api

```
app.put('/stock/:id', async(req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            console.log(id);
            const qunatity = req.body.quantity.quantity;
            const book = await bookCollections.findOne({_id: ObjectId(id)});
            const newUpdate = parseInt(book.quantity) + parseInt(qunatity);
            const result = await bookCollections.updateOne({_id:ObjectId(id)},
               $set({qunatity: newUpdate})
            )
            res.send(result);
        })
```

My question is, why should I use Id? and where can I get it? without Id it gets `networkErrro`

Answer (score 0):

Put method is used to update data.
The id you are providing to the api will be used to retrieved that row from your database which you want update. As you may know that in a database table every data row must have a unique id.

So for your book object , if you are retrieving it from the database in the first place then you should have a Id with that book data you got.

You have to provide that book id on the put request.

Comment: I gave the id which is I am getting from a get method and displayed other info in the page, I got the id also from that get method, I passed that id like this ` axios. put(`URL`/stock/${book._id},` but still I am getting this error

Comment: Is your nodejs project running correctly?